# Reasons to use BinaryFormatter instead of protobuf-net

Tags: c#, performance, serialization, protobuf-net, binaryformatter

So in many benchmarks I've seen, protobuf-net comes well ahead of BinaryFormatter: 
 - http://theburningmonk.com/2011/08/performance-test-binaryformatter-vs-protobuf-net/
 - https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance

Which leads me to the question: Why would you want to use BinaryFormatter if protobuf-net is available?

I have read something about BinaryFormatter storing type metadata, something that protobuf does not do. Can you give me an example scenario where I would want type metadata to be stored?

Comment: I've seen the question; I'm just not aware of any scenarios where I would want to choose `BinaryFormatter` ;p

Comment: I've taken a look to the benchmark and seem pretty unfair and in favor of BinaryFormatter,  since protobuf does not implement natively reference mapping, protobuffer stores the datas event the reference is the same.

Comment: Sorry could not complete the comment (passed the max delay). The test is serializing "100,000 iden­ti­cal instances", so BinaryFormatter stores 1 data & 100K references. On they other side, protobuf stores copy of the datas totaly. The test isn't representative of the power of protobuf, since we  will never need to send 100 K identical record, I will call this test "unfair". :)

Comment: cant compare those serializers. protobuf does not support cyclical object graphs (references), the modern trend to go directed graph-only comes from data marshaling needs in non-homogeneous systems. protobuf is built for that, just like Thrift and many others.  BinFrmtr is a "transparent" CLR graph serlzr which is needed in many cluster-like systems where native CLR objects need to be spread across the cluster just for the sake of performance and object portability is not needed. Keep in mind though, BinFormtr is VERY slow, and it does not have to be. There are alternatives like NFX Slim

Comment: in any case, THERE IS a STRONG USE CASE for BinFmter (and the like). There is much need in cluster systems to spread the load between the machines, for that some data needs to be "moved over". It is sometimes very inconvenient to create just DTO(data transfer objects) just to move data, for that many "duck typing" lang proponents hate the "classic OOP" languages - the proliferation of "garbage DTO types". Native CLR object serializers allow one to REUSE existing objects already in place for the purpose of business logic in most cases. Added link below to NFX Slim Serializer which is way faster

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently struggling with protobuf-net to serialize objects of type `Dictionary<string, object>`. What I've read is that it's not possible, so I guess that's a scenario where one would prefer BinaryFormatter.

Comment: The Dictionary<> uses ISerializable custom method to store its contents and comparers. You would either uses BinaryFormatter or use this (which is like 10 times faster): https://github.com/aumcode/nfx/blob/master/Source/NFX/Serialization/Slim/SlimSerializer.cs  (I am the author)